# Stable Spring version release

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, version, spring-3

Right now I am trying to research on how stable Spring release are right now. I'm having problems determining whether the most current Spring release (3.1.1) is the best choice for a base architecture. Are there any differences between 3.0 and 3.1? If so are there any impact in terms of coding structure just like migrating from spring 2.0 to 3.0. Currently we have a base architecture for Spring 2.0 and we are thinking of migrating to 3.X for integrated AJAX support and integrated REST support as well. Are there any other perks in migrating to 3.X? Is it good idea to migrate to Spring 3.0? If yes are there any drawbacks in migrating also which version is the best to migrate to? Thanks for taking time in reading this, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any differences between 3.0 and 3.1?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/changelog.txt

EDIT:
ok, it that's too technical, try this:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html

EDIT 2:
no, you do not **have to** use annotations. That's just a convenience feature mostly.

EDIT 3:
in [Implementing Controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller) all annotation based configurations have their XML-schema based counterparts. That said, unless you have very good reasons against annotations, you might try to gradually switch to this paradigm, as it is easier to read thus easier to maintain. (at least in in my opinion)

Comment: I've read the changelogs, but I can't seem to find any useful information aside from internal architecture changes which is very minor in my opinion (also I can't even remotely understand most of the entries). What I meant by changes in that is in coding structure like when migrate to spring 3.0 from 2.0 you have to convert your codes into annotation type controller. But thank you the link anyways.

Comment: @zerostasis: added one more link

Comment: Really I don't? Well apparently the old method for driving your Spring 2.0 is deprecated on Spring 3.0. And based on what I read (at least back when 3.0 was just released) was that in 1-2 years deprecated codes of Spring will be remove permanently and will not be supported. If this is not the case would you care enlighten me more.

Comment: @zerostasis: I've yet to find some spring documentation which says that XML-based configuration is -or ever will be- deprecated. Where did you read that?

Comment: I assumed this xml-based configuration deprecation situation from our 2 year old research back then. We assumed that xml-based configuration is being replace by annotation-driven mvc since SimpleFormController was deprecated back then. Since we used SimpleFormController as the backbone of our architecture and that most of the support is going to annotation-driven mvc that is being introduced we decided to retain at spring 2.0. If this is not true and that there is a way to retain xml-based configuration without using any deprecated classes, could you kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: @zerostasis : updated the answer with a link to example/documentation

Answer (score 0):

I've migrated some projects from spring 2.5.6 to spring-3.1 without any major problems. I can't speak to spring-3.1.1, but if its a non-milestone release I would be comfortable upgrading myself.

Here's a link to spring-3.1 features: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html

If you're moving up from 2.x to 3.x I don't see any reason why you would NOT upgrade to 3.1, even if you don't see immediate use for 3.1 features.

Comment: What do you mean by non-milestone release? Also what I'm afraid of is making another architecture base on Spring 3.0 or 3.1 and then the Spring community suddenly decided another major revision which renders my architecture to be obsolete in 2-3 years.

Comment: spring usually release milestones (with M1 or M2 in version) which are  less stable. Final releases are usually very stable. And I don't understand your comment about a future major revision that causes a change to your architecture. You're never under obligation to upgrade if you don't see benefit in the new features. And you can't predict nor control what will happen in the future with respect to spring releases, so why worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some minor differences between Spring 3.0 and 3.1, some of them are well  documented through the book [Pro Spring 3](http://www.apress.com/9781430241072), basically the JPA support has been improved with helper features like the `spring-data` project, the support of some standard compliant Java EE annotations and the possibility to create beans ["profiles"](http://blog.frankel.ch/spring-profiles-or-not-profiles) inside your xml configuration that can be handy when used alongside with maven, among others features.

Migrating from 2.0 to 3.x shouldn't be problematic if you stick to the old `xml` based configuration

Comment: If I may ask. Is the old XML based configuration the one that is deprecated on Spring 3.0?

Comment: AFAIK the XML based configuration is not deprecated, neither  superseded by another xml file-structure. Until now, there are still 3 ways to do configuration in spring, programmatically, by xml, and by annotations (although with annotations you have to write some basic xml), every one has its pros and cons, and some scenarios favors one over another

Comment: If that is true then could you kindly direct me to a comparison of pros and cons for this approaches. Also which approach are you most comfortable personally. Also I'm sorry for asking to much. I've been away from Spring for so long that I need help on how to implement each approach.

Comment: Don't worry, a good comparison is in the [chapter 5](http://books.google.co.ve/books?id=k7KZkl4PyhYC&lpg=PP1&hl=es&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false) (page 113) of the citated book (if you're lucky enough maybe you can consult the whole chapter in google books). In our projects we use the annotation style configuration; is shorter, easy, elegant, extensible (you can add your own), you don't have to search through a bunch of files when a development change is need and the requirements and the configuration requirements are isolated in the class (again, not need to navigate another extra files)